# How to get Invoice details by Invoice Id in XERO API using C#

Tags: c#, xero-api

I am able to get the `Invoice` details by using `Total` or `AmountPaid` as shown below:

```
var invoices = public_app_api.Invoices.Where("Total=100").Find();

var invoices = public_app_api.Invoices.Where("AmountPaid=100").Find();
```

I am unable to get the `Invoice` details by `InvoiceID` like..

```
var invoices = public_app_api.Invoices.Where("InvoiceID=c5b238f4-1356-4cad-89d0-681b6d182ea7").Find();

ERROR AS:- Xero.Api.Infrastructure.Exceptions.BadRequestException: 'No property or field 'c5b238f4' exists in type 'Invoice''
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Didnt you ask this a couple of hours ago?

Answer (score 2):

As per [the docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses#get-modified), a filter should look something like:

> Type=="BANK"

As such, your:

```
Where("InvoiceID="+ID)
```

line should instead be:

```
Where(@"InvoiceID==""" + ID + @"""")
```

The key difference is the use of `==` rather than `=` and the `"` surrounding the `ID` value.

If that doesn't work, try using the [`GUID` format](https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/36617144):

```
var invoices = public_app_api.Invoices.Find(
    new System.Guid("c5b238f4-1356-4cad-89d0-681b6d182ea7"));
```

Comment: Invoice Id In GUID Format,may because of this i am getting error?

Comment: Yes It's ,Issue with Invoice Id GUID Format.It's Working fine now .